# Windows Server 2008 R2 Upgrade to Server 2012 R2 issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows Server 2008 R2 upgrade to 2012 R2 issue.  Hoping someone can shed some light on my issue.  I am trying to update a Poweredge T410 running Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2.  It almost completes the upgrade and fails at the very end with the following error below.  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

2021-12-01 18:10:14, Error      [0x06413c] IBSLIB FindVolume: Unable to find volume marked as [$Setup_InstallVolume$][gle=0x00000002]

2021-12-01 18:10:14, Error      [0x064225] IBSLIB FindVolume: Failed while looking for [$Setup_InstallVolume$]; hr = 0x80070490.[gle=0x00000002]

Comment: check everything basic, chkdsk, sfc and ensure any updates has already been installed. hopefully you had already backups or snapshot to revert the changes.... mostly the problem is that the driver are not more fitting for 2012 so hence you need any drivers for the upgrade first and import them via pnputil